# Setting a variable through Spring in a dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two separate classes, each class is in a different jar. Class B is a dependency of A. I want to be able to pass a value in a variable in Class A (a url loaded from a config file) into B. However, I am having trouble doing so as the value is always being populated as null.

```
public class A {

@Value("${url.name}")
private String url;

...

B b = new B();
```

Here is my class B

```
@Component
public class B implements BInterface {

@Autowired
private String url
```

I have debugged and confirmed that the URL loads successfully in class A, but however doesn't seem to get passed into B. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Please note that class B is in a completely separate JAR from A, and I think that is where the heart of the problem lies. Essentially, I would like to know the best way that I can pass a value that is in a JAR in class A, and then pass that value to a class in class B whose JAR is a dependency or A.

Comment: you could use the setter of url in class B.

Comment: Wanted to try this the Spring way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class A, you cannot call `new B()` if you expect it to come from the Spring context.

How about `@Autowire` class B in A as such.

```
public class A {

@Value("${url.name}")
private String url;

...

@Autowire
private B b;
```

Also, you can't autowire a String property.  So how about `@Value` the Sring URL in class B also.

```
@Component
public class B implements BInterface {

@Value("${url.name}")
private String url;
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, the value in the other class still remains empty.

Comment: So the problem was that elsewhere in my code I was doing url = new String(); not realizing that would wipe the old contents of the passed through value. Figured it out as I was preparing an example for you. Thanks for the help.